# Get element from a List<Class> of classes

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-objects

I have a class called Employee that represents each employee in a company.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a new List of Employees

```
public readonly List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();
```

Now i want to find an employee from the list by his\her name but i don't know how to achieve that so your help will be very appreciated and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-Linq approach using [`List.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fh1w7y8z.aspx)

```
List<Employee> foundEmployees = Employees
    .FindAll(e => e.LastName.Equals(empName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Used the `Equals` approach to show you how to search ignoring the case.

Answer (score 3):

Using a LINQ-query:

```
Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.FirstName == "Rune" && emp.LastName == "S");
```

This will return you the first employee by that name, or if none are found, `null`. To get all employees with the name, use `Where` instead:

```
Employees.Where(emp => emp.FirstName == "Rune" && emp.LastName == "S");
```

Comment: I believe you're missing an equal sign in `emp.FirstName = "Rune"`

Comment: @Sam so I was, but I also believe I managed to fix it before your comment :)

Comment: impressive speed, sir! +1 for taking into consideration both first AND last name, rather than assuming the OP want one or the other.

Comment: @Sam oh well, I don't know if any of them are better or worse.. There's 10 identical answers, all posted within 3 minutes of each other. The last guy, who was 2 minutes later than the others probably uses a browser without websockets, so he didn't get the memo. I think I'll just lurch back to my "obscure framework" part of stackoverflow now. It's much more peaceful there...

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use LINQ, you could simply query the List:

```
Employees.Where(e => e.FirstName == "John" || e.LastName == "Doe");
```

Or, you could also quite easily loop through the list and add any matches to another resulting list:

```
List<Employee> matches = new List<Employee>();

foreach(var employee in Employees)
{
    if(employee.FirstName == "John" || employee.LastName == "Doe")
        matches.Add(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use LINQ

```
var employee = Employees.Where(e => e.LastName == lastname).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) will give you a `IEnumerable<Employee>` of employees with matched first and last name:

```
string firstName = "Bob";
string LastName = "Smith";
var employees = Employees.Where(e => e.FirstName == firstName && 
                                     e.LastName == lastName);
```

Or with query syntax:

```
var employees = from e in Employees
                where e.FirstName == firstName && 
                      e.LastName == lastName
                select e;
```

If there should be only one employee matching that criteria, then use [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274.aspx):

```
Employee employee = Employees.SignleOrDefault(e => e.FirstName == firstName && 
                                                   e.LastName == lastName);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say "find by his/her name" do you mean that you're looking for all of the people named "John" for example?  Using LINQ, that would look like this:

```
var johns = Employees.Where(e => e.FirstName == "John");
```

Keep in mind that this returns an `IEnumerable<Employee>` instead of an `IList<Employee>`.  There are a number of differences between the two.

`.Where()` is one of [many extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0.aspx) that you can use to query and manipulate your lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop, or use a LINQ:

This expression gives you the first employee with the last name "Smith", or `null` if nobody by this last name is found on your list:

```
var res = Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.LastName  == "Smith");
```

This loop lets you enumerate all employees with the first name "John":

```
foreach (var employee in Employees.Where(e => e.FirstName  == "John")) {
    ...
}
```

You can also make a list of employees passing a given filter:

```
var smiths = Employees.Where(e => e.LastName  == "Smith").ToList();
```

If the original list contains no "Smith"s, the resulting list would be empty.

If you must not use LINQ, you can use a plain `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var employee in Employees) {
    if (employee.LastName == "Smith") {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: from the 10 answers i think the best one is to use .FindAll(employees => Equals(employees.FirstName, employee.FirstName)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use next code snippet to

```
var firstName = "Jon";
var lastName = "Skeet";
var employees = Employees.Where(emp => emp.FirstName == firstName && emp.LastName == lastName);
```

If you want to find exactly one employee, then you probably want to use `Single` instead of `Where`, which in my case is more plausible. In case if you want to find the first employee, that fits that criteria, use 'First` instead of 'Where'.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Check out the example for WHERE simple1 and simple2.

Comment: Could you post the example you're speaking of here, rather than a link?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using LINQ:

```
var employees = Employees.Where(e => e.FirstName.Equals("RuneS")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wild card search use contains.

Employees.Where(emp => emp.FirstName.Contains("Rune") && emp.LastName.Contains("S"));

Comment: Where? There are 3 instances of the word "contains" (2 are in my answer).  I don't see where this code is listed on the answer. If I am mistaken then I apologize.